# Subtract value from particular row using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, csv, group-by, yahoo-finance

I am a beginner of Python.I tried to get the value of SP500 for 1 year by the below code.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
import glob


table=pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
df = table[0]
df.to_csv('S&P500-Info.csv')
df.to_csv("S&P500-Symbols.csv", columns=["Symbol"])

source_files = sorted(Path('SP500_update/').glob('*.csv'))

dataframes = []
for file in source_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file) # additional arguments up to your need
    df['source'] = file.name
    dataframes.append(df)

all = pd.concat(dataframes)
all = all.set_index("Date")
```

```
              Open          High      Low         Close     Adj Close    Volume     source
Date                            
2019-05-28  68.430000   68.860001   66.959999   67.080002   66.479050   2984700.0   A.csv
2019-05-29  66.589996   67.989998   66.589996   67.300003   66.697075   3722100.0   A.csv
2019-05-30  67.589996   67.900002   66.730003   66.889999   66.290756   2947900.0   A.csv
2019-05-31  66.239998   67.559998   66.070000   67.050003   66.449326   2829300.0   A.csv
2019-06-03  67.040001   68.099998   66.820000   66.989998   66.389854   2560600.0   A.csv
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2020-05-19  131.050003  135.759995  130.080002  134.339996  134.339996  3335300.0   ZTS.csv
2020-05-20  136.199997  137.070007  133.039993  133.339996  133.339996  2303400.0   ZTS.csv
2020-05-21  133.789993  133.889999  129.899994  130.330002  130.330002  1413100.0   ZTS.csv
2020-05-22  129.600006  130.779999  128.880005  130.110001  130.110001  1602400.0   ZTS.csv
2020-05-26  131.419998  132.880005  130.160004  130.619995  130.619995  1760775.0   ZTS.csv
```

For example,let the value of ['Close'] of ZTS.csv in 2019-05-31 = x

```
             Open           High       Low        Close     Adj Close    Volume     source    diff
Date                            
2019-05-28  68.430000   68.860001   66.959999   67.080002   66.479050   2984700.0   A.csv    67.080002-67.050003
2019-05-29  66.589996   67.989998   66.589996   67.300003   66.697075   3722100.0   A.csv    67.300003-67.050003
2019-05-30  67.589996   67.900002   66.730003   66.889999   66.290756   2947900.0   A.csv    66.889999-67.050003
2019-05-31  66.239998   67.559998   66.070000   67.050003   66.449326   2829300.0   A.csv    67.050003-67.050003
2019-06-03  67.040001   68.099998   66.820000   66.989998   66.389854   2560600.0   A.csv    66.989998-67.050003
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2020-05-19  131.050003  135.759995  130.080002  134.339996  134.339996  3335300.0   ZTS.csv  134.339996-x
2020-05-20  136.199997  137.070007  133.039993  133.339996  133.339996  2303400.0   ZTS.csv  133.339996-x
2020-05-21  133.789993  133.889999  129.899994  130.330002  130.330002  1413100.0   ZTS.csv  130.330002-x
2020-05-22  129.600006  130.779999  128.880005  130.110001  130.110001  1602400.0   ZTS.csv  130.110001-x
2020-05-26  131.419998  132.880005  130.160004  130.619995  130.619995  1760775.0   ZTS.csv  130.619995-x
```

I want to find out the value of all['Close'] groupby all['source]'in 2019-05-31, and then subract to the column all['Close'] groupby all['source'],and get the new row all['diff'].
If the value of all['diff'] is below than 0. I want to find it out.I want to print out the date of all['diff'] are below 0 and show what source of the date belongs to.Can anybody tell me how can I get the result?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this to filter your data frame

```
all_filtered = all.query('diff < 0')
```

then print the info you want

Comment: thanks @Krustibat !
How can I get the value of all['diff']  by group all['source]?